# Flutter conditional statement for getter

Tags: flutter

I've this in my application:

```
LocalTextItem? get text =>
      FocusedItemModel.of(context).focused as LocalTextItem;
```

The idea was if user taps a text item and then goes to text editor page, the text can be customized.

But right now I need to implement adding new text. So the user might not tap any existing text and navigate straight to text editor page and customize a new text.

For this I need some conditional statements like:

```
if(text = null){
    initEmptyText();
}
```

Or in the text canvas for building styles and others:

```
fontFamily: text != null ? text.fontFamily : GoogleFonts.lato().fontFamily,
```

But I am getting an: `Unexpected Null value` error.

So in short if the user has not selected any text I need to initialize an empty `textCanvas` and if the user did select a text I will simply put all the properties on the `textCanvas`. `FocusedItemModel` is as below:

```
class FocusedItemModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  static FocusedItemModel of(BuildContext context) =>
      Provider.of<FocusedItemModel>(
        context,
        listen: false,
      );

  LocalMovableItem? _focused;
  LocalMovableItem get focused => _focused!;
  bool get hasFocus => _focused != false;

  /*
    Set an item to focus
  */
  void focus(LocalMovableItem? item) {
    if (_focused != null) {
      unfocus();
    }
    if ((_focused != item && item!.focusable)) {
      _focused = item;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  bool hasFocusOn(LocalMovableItem? item) => _focused == item;

  void unfocus() {
    if (_focused != null) {
      _focused = null;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  /*
    Notify all listeners
  */
  void redraw() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void notifyChange() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I've also defined the providers in `Multiproviders`

Comment: your focused is null in several cases yet you are asserting it as non null

Comment: I’m quite new to providers and stuff. And to this day this project was handled by someone else. Can you point me out how can I assert it as nullable?

Comment: perhaps is `if(text == null)` ?

Comment: as long as I have this: `LocalTextItem? get text =>
      FocusedItemModel.of(context).focused as LocalTextItem;` in my code I'm getting the error in the unexpected error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may need more code to understand what's happening here, but first problem is here :

```
LocalMovableItem get focused => _focused!;
```

You're basically asserting that `_focused` can't be null with the `!` operator, which is wrong since this variable is set to `null` in your `unfocus` method.

You should update your Getter with the following

```
LocalMovableItem? get focused => _focused;
```

After doing so, you should update your cast to

```
LocalTextItem? get text =>
      FocusedItemModel.of(context).focused as LocalTextItem?;
```

Btw, note that this cast won't work if your models `LocalTextItem` and `LocalMovableItem` aren't related.